# How to ask for confirmation and use e.PreventDefault on click event

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to implement some very basic (in my opinion) functionality with jQuery. I have `Delete` link:

```
<a href="/Delete" class="prompt-for-delete">Delete</a>
```

and all I want is when the link is clicked to show some kind of confirmation window like:

**Are you sure you want to delete this : Yes/No**

And if `No` is clicked I want to prevent the link from executing. I use `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and
`jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js` my HTML is:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" ></div>
<a href="/Delete" class="prompt-for-delete">Delete</a>
```

I tried several options I found on the internet. The last one is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.prompt-for-delete').click(function (e) {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete all items": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

which is just to get something working but with this I get the dialog opened and automatically closed after a second. It seems like something very standard so could you provide an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Confirm()` is what you are looking for. This is how you use it:

```
var answer=confirm('Do you want to delete?');
```

Your HTML would be like:

```
<a id="delete" href="/Delete" class="prompt-for-delete">Delete</a>
```

And your javascript:

```
$('#delete').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer=confirm('Do you want to delete?');
    if(answer){
     alert('Deleted');
    }
    else{
        alert('Not Deleted');      
    }
});
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/c9cLW/1/

Edit:

Here is updated redirection and preventing event:

Script:

```
$('#delete').on('click',function(e){
    var answer=confirm('Do you want to delete?');
    if(answer){
     alert('Deleted');
    }
    else{
     e.preventDefault();      
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9cLW/5/

Comment: I like this approach. But why you put `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning? I've tried in Fiddle `if(answer){e.preventDefault();}` and it seem to work ok. Is there any reason to put `e.preventDefault();` there?

Comment: that depends on whether you want to style it or not. I'm guessing the OP is using dialog for a reason and that so that he doesn't have the ugly javascript popups?

Comment: Also, when does this do the redirect? so this won't work either.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm for more on confirm. @Leron As an aside you probably don't want to be doing a delete (which by definition is destructive) on a GET request.

Comment: I'd generally suggest returning the confirm value rather than the preventDefault and if/else used here.

Comment: Please see the Edit. I updated the preventDefault and redirection events.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a  in the page, display a dialog and return the result:

```
<div id="divConfirmMessageDialog" class="ui-dialog" title="Confirm">
    <p id="confirmMessage"></p>
</div>

confirmDialog: function (message) {
    "use strict";
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $("#divConfirmMessageDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                def.resolve();
            },
            No: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                def.reject();
            }
        }
    });
    $("#confirmMessage").text(message);
    $("#divConfirmMessageDialog").dialog('open');
    return def.promise();
}

function remove() {
        confirmDialog('Items will be removed...Continue?').done(function () {
            return true;
        }).fail(function () {
            return false;
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dialog button clicks will be deffered. So you'll need to always cancel the click and then redirect manually:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.prompt-for-delete').click(function (e) {
         //get href of click
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //redirect manually ONLY on success.
                    window.location = href;
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        //always cancel the click.
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.prompt-for-delete').click(function (e) {
      if(!confirm('Do you want to delete?')){
           e.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9cLW/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="_blank" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) event.preventDefault()">click</a>
```